# how to get selected input fileds in a selected row by input name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can get input values of a selected row using following method. What I want is I want to modify this to get input values of certain fields which can have **fc,fs,hc** or **hs** as a part of a name.

```
    var data
    $('#'+rowid).find("input").each(function() {

                data += "|"+$(this).attr("name");
                data += ":"+this.value;

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for looking for inputs with **fc** as part of it's **name**:

```
$('#' + rowid + ' input[name*="fc"]').each()
```

Comment: @Sara: More information can be found here. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Simply check input fields names using this method :

```
if( "name".indexOf( "hc" ) !== -1 )
```

OR

```
$('#inputfieldId:contains("hc")')
```

Hope this helps..